# How to link csv file within a markdown file when using Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter

I would like to render rapid reports using the Markdown files with links to csv files [csv](path to csv file). This part is working, I can dowload the csv file from the markdown preview, but I can't open the file in the Jupyter Lab "Table". Is there is something to do about this?